# Footer needs to stick to bottom when content is less

Tags: html, css

I have an `aspx` page in which I have less content, due to that my '**footer**' is not sticking to bottom.

Please find html code for this

```
 <div style=" background: #eae8e7;
border-top: #d30000 4px solid;
min-height: 80px;
position: relative;
right: 0px;
bottom: 1px;
left: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;">
```

Please find `css` which i used :

```
.footer {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #eae8e7;
        border-top: #d30000 4px solid;
        bottom: 0px;
        position: inherit;
        clear: both;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to do that with CSS only, and not using `position:fixed` then this is what you need http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: @wf4: Not like that, you can suggest any way to achieve that

Comment: set `min-height` to the container

Comment: Will you please suggest how i define

Comment: if my answer is not what you want just tell me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
  box-sizing:         border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}


footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>This footer will always be positioned at the bottom of the page, but <strong>not fixed</strong>.</footer>
```

Try this change the position as fixed

Comment: this is fine but i dont want it to be as a position fixed.

Comment: why don't you use the frameworks like bootstrap or something

Comment: I have edited my code now just try

Comment: It does not work for me in safari at iphone 10.*

Answer (score 1):

```
.footer {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:17px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
}
```

As long as html is `position:relative`, this works.  No need for wrappers or anything like that :)

Comment: After using this code, i get this issue, please find the url of Screenshot :http://www.imagesup.net/?di=014214164269

Comment: Is your `html {position:relative;}`?

Comment: No i have no position for main div and your given code is not working

Comment: Can I see the general layout of your HTML and CSS?  This should work based on the fact that it's always worked for me.  Your HTML element itself needs to be position:relative

Comment: Actually i m using aspx and user control for webpage and my footer is added in User contol

Comment: Well, is your website in HTML?  I'd assume so...  I mean the actual code, not the page.

Comment: NO, I have 'aspx' page

Comment: But is your page's code in HTML?  It obviously is, since you used a div tag in your question... :/

Comment: Well position relative is not working for me when content is less in other page footer comes up

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        html,body{
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        #container{
            min-height: 90%;
            background-color: #f00;
        }
        #footer{
            min-height: 10%;
            background-color: #00f;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        it's the container
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        it's the footer
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```