# position div at bottom of screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a div at the bottom of the viewport but it doesnt seem to be working right. I have this set up

html

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.bottom{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

The trouble being that the parent div is getting its height from JS and adding some style to div dynamically like `<div class="parent" style="height: 483px;">` so then basically the div doesnt show up at the bottom until I resize the screen. Is there a way to dynamically get the screen size then add the css to make the div stick to the bottom?

Comment: Just to clarify the question, do you want to `.bottom` element to always be visible and positioned at the bottom of the screen? Or you want it to act like a footer and be visible only at the bottom of your document (in this case, it won't be visible if your content is bigger than your screen size)? From what I understood, [your code is working well](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/xswnnqed/)

Comment: I wanted it to always be visible at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: EyasSH's answer should do the trick. [Here is the kind of behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/xswnnqed/2/) it'll give to your `bottom` class element. Just apply `position:fixed;` to your `bottom` element.

Comment: Duplicated L Try this stack Question Answer : [enter link description here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985248/footer-needs-to-stick-to-bottom-when-content-is-less/27985504#27985504

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make div stay at bottom of page's content all the time even when there are scrollbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824831/make-div-stay-at-bottom-of-pages-content-all-the-time-even-when-there-are-scrol)

Comment: @JeffNoel I guess I should change the question a little. The .bottom is placed exactly where I want it to be with the current CSS its just isnt doing it on page load, I have to resize the browser window for it to show up. I think this is because the parent div's height is dynamically loaded by JS.

Comment: The CSS should react and adjust even if your content is loaded dynamically. I would suggest that you setup a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help us find a solution according to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Use `position: fixed;` instead of absolute. That'll position the element relative to the viewport, rather than the document.

This matters if your document ends up being longer than screen size.

Answer (score 1):

This will fix your problem

```
.bottom { 
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:2;
    width:100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. An element with a fixed position is positioned relative to the browser window, and will not move even if the window is scrolled. You should change the CSS

```
.bottom{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to position a footer at the bottom of the viewport? This might help: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Also, if you want .bottom to be positioned relative to .parent, you'll need to add position:relative to .parent. Then bottom:0 will place .bottom at the bottom of .parent.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is change the position of your div to fixed rather than absolute, so that the javascript's styling won't be a problem

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="bottom">
  </div>
</div>

.bottom{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
```